# Publishing go module in a monorepo envirnoment

Tags: go, go-modules

Suppose I have a monorepo and there are several individual golang services:

```
root    
└── services
        ├── svc1
        │   ├── go.mod
        │   ├── go.sum
        │   └── main.go
        └── svc2
            ├── go.mod
            ├── go.sum
            └── main.go
```

Whereas svc2 will depend on svc1 in the future. Also, it is a requirement that svc1 and svc2 can be released individually.

Is there a way I can publish the module indivdually? The go mod documentation only assume that there is only repo so it doesn't provide such flexibility.

Comment: The semantic version of the module is determined by repository tags, so I don't think you will be able to version each module separately in the same repository (at least on git).

Comment: You may find this section of the go wiki helpful https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#should-i-have-multiple-modules-in-a-single-repository

Answer (score 18):

To tag a release version for a module within a subdirectory of a repository, add the subdirectory as a prefix of the tag, like `svc1/v0.1.0`.

Per https://golang.org/ref/mod#vcs-version:

> If a module is defined in a subdirectory within the repository …, then each tag name must be prefixed with the module subdirectory, followed by a slash. For example, the module `golang.org/x/tools/gopls` is defined in the `gopls` subdirectory of the repository with root path `golang.org/x/tools`. The version `v0.4.0` of that module must have the tag named `gopls/v0.4.0` in that repository.

Comment: I was searching for this for hours and almost gave up thinking this might not be possible. Not sure why Google doesn't rank it from search higher.